# Selecting date and an option from a drop-down list

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, html-select

I need to download price after choosing date and table option in this website https://eximbank.com.vn/WebsiteExrate/Gold_vn_2012.aspx

The code is below. However, it only download data for the current date and latest price even I did use the loop: For next to choose table option. Could anyone help me with this issue? I think the command to choose date and time may not actually work. Many thanks in advance!

```
Sub Eximbank()

Dim XMLRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim i As Integer

XMLRequest.Open "GET", "https://eximbank.com.vn/WebsiteExrate/Gold_vn_2012.aspx", False
XMLRequest.send

If XMLRequest.Status <> 200 Then
MsgBox XMLRequest.Status & " - " & XMLRequest.statusText
Exit Sub
End If

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLRequest.responseText

n = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & n) = Now
For i = 1 To 10
HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("CalControl1_TextBox1")(0).Value = "13/04/2020"
HTMLDoc.getElementById("ddlQuoteCount").Value = "i"
HTMLDoc.getElementById("ImageButton1").Click


 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & n) = HTMLDoc.getElementById("lblQUOTETM").innerText
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & n) = HTMLDoc.getElementById("GoldRateRepeater_lblCSHBUYRT_0").innerText
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & n) = HTMLDoc.getElementById("GoldRateRepeater_lblCSHSELLRT_0").innerText
 Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You need a POST request to provide the alternate date info. Whether or not you can replicate all the necessary info via xhr you will need to experiment and see. As it is aspx it is likely you will need the event info e.g event state.

Comment: Hi QHarr, I tried a POST request but I can't find something like "Request Header" and "Content-Type" in the network URL at all.